# ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory message converter is ignored when configuring listeners automatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I need to create Kafka listeners at runtime, and everything seems working, except that the message converter property seems being ignored (or maybe this is a designed feature or I've made something wrong).

When using `@KafkaListener`, it works correct, but when creating listeners manually my message isn't converted to a desired object and I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.my.company.model.MyPojo (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.my.company.model.MyPojo is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.my.company.config.MyPojo.kafka.KafkaConfig.lambda$createListenerContainers$2(KafkaConfig.java:142)
```

My configuration:

```
@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {    
    var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());       
    return factory;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerContainer createListenerContainer1() {
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topicConfig("my_topic"));
    var container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory(), containerProperties);
    //tried this too...
    //var container = kafkaListenerContainerFactory().createContainer(topicConfig("my_topic")); 
    container.setupMessageListener((MessageListener<String, MyPojo>) data -> getDataService.process(data.value()););
    container.start();

    return container;
}
```

The WORKING Kafka listener:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "1", topics = "my_topic)
public void listenGetDataTopic(@Payload MyPojo message) {
    log.info(message);
}
```

I've tried a lot of different configs and to debug it deeply, and, of course I see the difference between handling messages when using `@KafkaListener` and manually created listeners, but I didn't figure out how to apply a message conversion to a manually created listeners. Is there a possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The message converter is not a property of the container, it is a property of the listener adapter used to invoke the pojo method for the `@KafkaListener`.

When using a container directly, your listener must implement `MessageListener` or one of its sub-interfaces.

You can either invoke the converter yourself in your listener (e.g. create a lightweight adapter) or you need to use another technique for dynamically creating `@KafkaListener`s.

See

[Kafka Spring: How to create Listeners dynamically or in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715268/kafka-spring-how-to-create-listeners-dynamically-or-in-a-loop)

[Kafka Consumer in spring can I re-assign partitions programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69465733/kafka-consumer-in-spring-can-i-re-assign-partitions-programmatically/69466302#69466302)

[Can i add topics to my @kafkalistener at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744775/can-i-add-topics-to-my-kafkalistener-at-runtime/68745230#68745230)

for some examples of those techniques.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Is it possible to extend the configuration in a future to allow to configure mesage converter globally? (what, btw seems to be done since we assign it to a factory, but actually it works a little different)

Comment: I opened an issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2068